# Condition in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like

```
 select * from emp where emp.id in(1,2,3) and emp.sal>10000
```

I need to add a logic to the check emp.sal>10000 only if design.type='Labor', I tried like the below but not working

```
select * from emp,design where emp.id in(1,2,3) and case when design.type='Labor' then emp.sal>10000
```

Can we implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
select * from emp where emp.id in(1,2,3) and (design.type<>'Labor' OR emp.sal>10000)
```

If design.type='Labor' then emp.sal must be greater than 10000 for the condition to be true.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
SELECT * FROM emp 
WHERE emp.id IN (1,2,3) 
   AND ((design.type = 'Labor' AND emp.sal>10000) 
        OR (design.type <> 'Labor'))
```

The simplification of the OR condition would be..

```
SELECT * FROM emp 
WHERE emp.id IN (1,2,3) 
   AND (design.type <> 'Labor' OR emp.sal > 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to query rows that have a salary higher than 10000 only when the type is `labor` for completion's sake, we will also state that for different `type`s we don't care about the salary. If we put this formally, we'll get:

```
(type = 'Labor' and salary > 10000) OR (type != 'Labor')
```

This boolean expression can of course be simplified - we're looking for rows that either have a type different than `Labor` or a salary higher than 10000:

```
(salary > 10000) OR (type != 'Labor')
```

So if we put it all together:

```
SELECT *
FROM   emp 
WHERE  (emp.id IN (1,2,3)) AND (type != 'Labor' OR sal > 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this.
  select * from 
  (
    select * from emp where id in (1,2,3) and design.type='Labor'
  )a
  where a.sal>10000;
```